# Use a "t" in a socket already used by another process

Tags: networking, sockets

I want to read (man-in-the-middle, if you will) traffic on a socket that another process has already opened.

I am doing this for debuging purposes.

I have a process (firefox) that is using a connection to a server, described by lsof as

```
 firefox   595 user   84u  IPv4 6384178      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.105:43347->server:port (ESTABLISHED)
```

I think this connection is a long-lived http connection, and want to read the text both firefox and the server send into it.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch ALL the network connections with `wireshark`. From `man wireshark`:

```
xenial (1) wireshark.1.gz
Provided by: wireshark-qt_2.0.2+ga16e22e-1_i386 

NAME
       wireshark - Interactively dump and analyze network traffic

SYNOPSIS
       wireshark [ -a <capture autostop condition> ] ...
       [ -b <capture ring buffer option> ] ...  [ -B <capture buffer size> ]
       [ -c <capture packet count> ] [ -C <configuration profile> ] [ -D ]
       [ --display=<X display to use> ]  [ -f <capture filter> ]
       [ -g <packet number> ] [ -h ] [ -H ] [ -i <capture interface>|- ]
       [ -I ] [ -j ] [ -J <jump filter> ] [ -k ] [ -K <keytab> ] [ -l ] [ -L ]
       [ -m <font> ] [ -n ] [ -N <name resolving flags> ]
       [ -o <preference/recent setting> ] ...  [ -p ] [ -P <path setting>]
       [ -r <infile> ] [ -R <read (display) filter> ] [ -s <capture snaplen> ]
       [ -S ] [ -t a|ad|adoy|d|dd|e|r|u|ud|udoy ] [ -v ] [ -w <outfile> ]
       [ -X <eXtension option> ] [ -y <capture link type> ]
       [ -Y <displaY filter> ] [ -z <statistics> ] [ <infile> ]

DESCRIPTION
       Wireshark is a GUI network protocol analyzer.  It lets you
       interactively browse packet data from a live network or from a
       previously saved capture file.  Wireshark's native capture file format
       is pcap format, which is also the format used by tcpdump and various
       other tools.
```